# How to create folder using google drive api in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

I have tried to create folder in a `flutter app` in a `google drive account`. It shows me a `bad argument(s) error`. Although i am working with the documentation examples

Here is the code i have tried to do. it generates

> "Bad argument(s)" error.

```dart
final _SCOPES = [drive.DriveApi.DriveScope];

  void adrive(){

clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials,_SCOPES).then(onValue).catchError((e)=>print(e));
  }


  FutureOr onValue(AuthClient client)  {
    //drive.DriveApi(client).files.list().then((value)=>print(value.items[0]));
    // The previous line works fine
    drive.File r = new drive.File();
    r.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    r.title = "hello";

    drive.DriveApi(client).files.insert(r,uploadOptions: commons.UploadOptions.Resumable).then((f)=>print(f.mimeType+" "+f.originalFilename))
          .catchError((ex)=>print(ex.toString()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have already done `Auth credentials`, you can use this 
Simple function to create folder in Google Drive.

```
clientViaServiceAccount(credentials, scopes).then((http_client) async {
              var _drive = v3.DriveApi(http_client);
              var _createFolder = await _drive.files.create(
                v3.File()
                  ..name = 'FileName'
                  ..parents = ['1f4tjhpBJwF5t6FpYvufTljk8Gapbwajc'] // Optional if you want to create subfolder
                  ..mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',  // this defines its folder
              );
            });
```

Comment: I'm unable to create a folder and upload a file to it, the above code does not work, can you help me? I get an Exception telling me the file is not found, which is specified in the parents property

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming late but I hope I'll make some help for others who want to get folder's id,
this code I convert it to a flutter from java code from Google official
[Google Official Workspace](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/folder).

First you can make a dart class, to authenticate the user:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class GoogleAuthClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final Map<String, String> _headers;

  final http.Client _client = http.Client();

  GoogleAuthClient(this._headers);

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    return _client.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));
  }
}
```

Then create the folder function:

```
import 'package:YOUR_APP_NAME/google_auth_client.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as drive;
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart' as signIn;


  Future<String?> createFolder() async {
    final googleSignIn =
        signIn.GoogleSignIn.standard(scopes: [drive.DriveApi.driveScope]);
    final signIn.GoogleSignInAccount? account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final authheader = await account?.authHeaders;

    var client = GoogleAuthClient(authheader!);
    var driveFile = drive.DriveApi(client);

    // File's metadata.
    var fileMetadata = drive.File();
    fileMetadata.name = 'test';
    fileMetadata.mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder';

    try {
      var file = await driveFile.files.create(fileMetadata);
      print('Folder ID: ${file.id}');
      return file.id;
    } catch (e) {
      // TODO: Handle error appropriately
      print('Unable to create folder: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

This will create the folder and gives you the Folder's ID that you will use to upload the file to it.

Comment: Hoe to authenticate the user did you use it directly ?

Comment: Oh no, to get to google drive authentication I got more steps to follow, I'll try to explain in short, first I add packages as googleapis and google_sing_in then create firebase project and add to it android app so I got need to make SHA1 for firebase, then its automatically created an app in google cloud console with all api keys that we need, also I downloaded the google_service.json from firebase that has all credentials for my app.